# Get a value from JSON: Undefined property: stdClass::$id

Tags: php, json, mongodb

I am trying to the the "project_id" value from a JSON file, to check with the database if this is unique or not. I will add my code to elaborate on my problem.

```
$jsonDecode = json_decode(file_get_contents(/path/to/json.json));
// ERROR OCCURS ON THIS LINE 
$project_id = $jsonDecode[0]->project_id;

//      Opening a connection with the database
$m = new MongoClient();
$db = $m->Database;
$collection = $db->test;

//      Find a document with the same Project ID
$cursor = $collection->findOne(array("project_id" => $project_id));
```

My JSON is formatted like this:

```
[{"project_id": 66, "project_code": 14070169, "nr_samples": 96, "samples": [{EMBEDDED DOCUMENT WITH DATA}, {EMBEDDED DOCUMENT WITH DATA}, ..... GOES ON FOR A LONG TIME}]
```

The specifc error which I am getting is:

> ErrorException in UploadExcelFileController.php line 340: Undefined
>   property: stdClass::$project_id

I don't understand what is going wrong here, because I am using the same code for a similar formatted JSON file and that works great! Could someone please help me out? I just want to get the value of "project_id" to query.

**UPDATE...**

Wow. I am so embarrassed. The file didn't contain a project_id key.. I was looking at the wrong JSON file. So now the code works. I am sorry!

Comment: Did you var_dump $jsonDecode to see what is in there?

Comment: Sure the json is valid? This is working on my pc `$returnValue = json_decode('[{"project_id": 66, "project_code": 14070169, "nr_samples": 96}]
');`

Comment: $jsonDecode comes back as: 'jsonDecode' => array(object(stdClass))

Comment: I am pretty convinced that the JSON is valid. Loading it in PHPStrom no errors are shown and it also imports into MongoDB are no problem!

Comment: http://jsonlint.com/ also says the JSON is valid

Comment: Yes, JSON is valid or `json_decode()` would have returned `null`. It isn't complaining about that, it's complaining about whatever object is located under the array's `0` key. Just run `var_dump($jsonDecode[0]);` and see it with your own eyes.

Comment: @AnnaJeanine Can you also provide the JSON which is working for you?

Comment: The var_dump($jsonDecode[0]); returns the whole JSON but the beginning is the most interesting: `object(stdClass)#225 (6) { ["project_code"]=> int(12352)`... What should I do with this because I am kinda lost right now..

Comment: I have updated my question.. found the problem. I am so sorry. I was looking in the wrong file. Thank you so much for helping me out!